# What are OLE Overridables in MFC?

Tags: mfc, overriding

What are "OLE Overridables" in MFC (as opposed to just Overridables)? What does OLE mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLE stands for "Object Linking and Embedding".  It is an old term for a technology invented by Microsoft that allows embedding controls in control containers and sending it data of various kinds (example here would be an Excel spreadsheet embedded in a Word document.)

Specifically relating to MFC, it sounds like you are referring to the "Overridables" section of an MFC .h file.  They are basically the OO way to handle events such as `OnDraw()`, `OnPaint()`, etc.
(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bst0130.aspx for more info).

Does this help?